# Splitting a list (?)

Tags: python, pandas

I've been searching for a while and I think I may have built the block wrong, but I'm hoping there is a simple solution. I need to break apart a list and every solution I could think of has failed, (limited knowledge). My code is built to look for specific words within the text and pulling the section that text is in, I am also adding the filename that the text was found in. However, this is all to the same list!

```
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if filename.path.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if pattern.search(line) != None:
                list.append((filename.name, line.rstrip('\n')))
                
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

when this prints it looks like:

*[('AEE_0000018654_10Q_20200331_Item1A_excerpt.txt', 'In 2019, Ameren Missouri entered into a build-transfer agreement to acquire, after construction, an up-to 300-megawatt wind generation facility. In 2018, Ameren Missouri entered into a build-transfer agreement to acquire, after construction, an up-to 400-megawatt wind generation facility. Unless relevant regulations are modified by the IRS or applicable legislation is enacted by Congress to include an extension of the December 31, 2020 in-service date criteria, if any portion of these facilities is completed '), ('AEE_0000018654_10Q_20200331_Item2_excerpt.txt', 'an up-to 400-megawatt wind generation facility. These two agreements are subject to customary contract terms and conditions. The two build-transfer acquisitions collectively represent $1.2 billion of capital expenditures and would support Ameren Missouri’s compliance with the Missouri renewable energy standard. Ameren Missouri and the developers continue to monitor the impact to each project schedule. To date, neither developer has reported to Ameren Missouri that the projects will not be completed in 2020. Ameren Missouri expects the up-to 400-megawatt project to be placed in-service by the end of 2020. However, at this time, due to manufacturing, shipping, and other supply chain issues, and based on Ameren Missouri’s discussions with the developer, Ameren Missouri expects that a portion of the up-to 300-megawatt project, representing approximately $100 million of investment, could be placed in-service in the first quarter of 2021.')]*

So, is there a way I can split this up so that the file name is in a separate list? I would like to use -

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={"col1": filename, "col2": list})
df.to_csv("./SECParse.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

but so far I am unable to break up this list I've created.

Any help?

Comment: Looks like you've got a list of tuples. Try this: `just_filenames = [filename for filename, _ in myList]`. FWIW, I _highly_ recommend not using `list` as a name for a variable. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), as it's a built-in. And `myList` replaced for your `list`...

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA Hey Jason, I gave that a try and made the adjust for list (thanks!) when I try to run this I receive ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: If Jason's method didn't work either then I think the problem is your list isn't actually a list of tuples. Try printing it again and double check that it's in the form [(filename,text),(filename,text)...]

Comment: I restarted the kernel as a last-ditch effort even though I had not too long before, and oddly enough it worked perfectly, however, I can still not run your code (Jeff).

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a list of tuples in the form `(filename,text)`, I think you can just call

```
pd.DataFrame(ls,columns=['filename','text'])
```

where `ls` is the list you generated from your `for` loop.

Output should look like this:

```
    filename                                        text
0   AEE_0000018654_10Q_20200331_Item1A_excerpt.txt  In 2019, Ameren Missouri entered into a build-...
1   AEE_0000018654_10Q_20200331_Item2_excerpt.txt   an up-to 400-megawatt wind generation facility...
```

Comment: When I make this adjustment, I receive  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (337, 1), indices imply (337, 2)    -I have alot more lines than the above example-

Comment: Hmm what version of pandas are you using? It might be because your version is older and it's seeing the list of tuples as a list of single elements.

Comment: Currently 1.1.0

Comment: After many attempts at what feels like the same thing ... it has worked!!!!